# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve asynchronously?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, prism

I am working on a WPF application that loads assemblies dynamically. We use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve to load the assemblies. The problem is that this is a static event delegate and when it runs, it runs on the dispatcher thread and thus blocks the UI from being responsive. Is there a way to get this event to work on a background thread? Or at least not block the UI while its working?

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Why does AssemblyResolve take a long time?

Answer (score 1):

The [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is fired *on the same thread* where you trying to resolve the type. I've just verified that using the sample code from [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), whit this minimal change:

```
Task.Run(() => InstantiateMyTypeFail(currentDomain)).Wait();
```

So, in your case, if you have an option to try resolving the dependency for the first time on a non-UI thread, you could simply do this:

```
await Task.Run(() => InstantiateMyTypeFail(currentDomain));
```

This would not block the UI.